# J2EE - Services Layer Design

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee

I´m going to build Restful Services Layer (Middleware) using Java/Spring/Eclipse. The goal of the service layer is exposing tons methods, that today exists in different systems.

The Middleware will have the standar layers for each Functional Unit, for example:

- UserFacade
- UserManager
- UserBeans
- UserDataAccess

I used to work with a single war project with all the clases inside. This is not good when working more than one team in differents requirements, with different deadlines.

As this is going to be a big project, I would like an architecture that simplify working with many teams in different requirements, and different deadlines.

**First question**:

What is best:

- Create one JAR per Layer (Facade, Managers, Beans, DataAccess)
- Create one JAR per Functional Unit (Users, Accounts, Bills, etc)
- Both, one Jar per Layer / Functional Unit (FacadeUser, FacadeManager, etc)

**Second question**:

- Should I create a Java Enterprise Application (EAR) with the Web application and modules?
- or can I simply create a Web application adding the JARS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a micro services approach - breaking it down by functional units. Whether you use EARs or WARs depends on what application server you are deploying to. But since you specifically mentioned restful service endpoints, multiple web applications, each application exposing specific business functions would suffice. Breaking your project into multiple manageable applications is usually better than building one monolithic application.

This is a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25625813/5150013